# AdBlock blocks MathJax and AddThis

Tags: javascript, mathjax, addthis, adblock

When AdBlock is enabled I got the following errors:

1. AddThis: `Uncaught Error: Must pass a string which will eval to a
   globally accessible object where callbacks will be stored`
2. MathJax: `Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as
   JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script
   in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
   'self' * 'unsafe-inline'".`

When AdBlock is disabled, everything works fine.

The problem appeared a couple of weeks ago.

Even when AdBlock is enabled everything works fine on sites that use MathJax: https://www.mathjax.org and https://math.stackexchange.com/

Possibly, something has changed and I need to change the code properly. How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. It looks like a CSP issue but it's unclear on which site you're seeing this.

Comment: I see the problem on https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/derivative-calculator/

Comment: There are many errors on the page when ad-blockers are around (e.g., jquery also fails to load), so I suspect there's some bad interaction between the rest of the JS on the page. For example, if I inject a fresh copy of MathJax into the DOM after the page has loaded (with ad blockers on), MathJax works fine so it is likely not a problem with MathJax as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both errors refer to the same Content Security Policy (CSP) issue which is that unsafe `eval()` calls are disallowed. Ad blockers, such as AdBlock and Adblock Plus, have recently started using CSPs for cases where traditional techniques are insufficient (see [Adblock Plus filter options](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#options)).

I was only able to reproduce it on emathhelp.net. There I was able to find the filter `||emathhelp.net^$csp=script-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline'` to be responsible for this which was added to the EasyList ad blocking list [on May 15](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/commit/7d89370d9#diff-ce6ade6e52352499cfb347f46c329f9fR5558). In Adblock Plus you can find such filters by following these steps:

1. Right-click anywhere on the page
2. Select "Inspect" in the context menu
3. Switch to the "Adblock Plus" tab in the window that opens
4. Reload the page to populate the list in the tab
5. Find the filter next to a request with the type "CSP"

You can reach out to EasyList ([GitHub](https://github.com/easylist/easylist), [forum](https://forums.lanik.us/), [website](https://easylist.to/)) to find out why they added a particular filter. They should also be able to help you restore any functionality that's broken.